# Google Maps, Directions and Places API to Generate Dynamic Directions

Tags: api, google-maps, maps, google-places-api, google-directions-api

**UPDATED CODE**: OK, I have this working the way I want it now, though I would like to order the results of the nearBy search by distance.

```
// Google Maps
var lat = $('#map').data('lat');
var lng = $('#map').data('lng');

var markerImage = {
    url: '/img/marker.png'
}

var eventTitle = $('.title').data('event-title');
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
var trainDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var trainService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var busDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var busService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var airportDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var airportService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

function initialise() {

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: latLng
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

    trainDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('train'));
    busDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('bus'));
    airportDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('airport'));

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map,
        title: eventTitle,
        icon: markerImage
    });

    var trainRequest = {
        location: latLng,
        radius: '500',
        types: ['train_station']
    };

    var busRequest = {
        location: latLng,
        radius: '500',
        types: ['bus_station']
    };

    var airportRequest = {
        location: latLng,
        radius: '50000',
        types: ['airport']
    };

    var train = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    var bus = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    var airport = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

    train.nearbySearch(trainRequest, trainRoute);
    bus.nearbySearch(busRequest, busRoute);
    airport.nearbySearch(airportRequest, airportRoute);
}

function trainRoute(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        var request = {
            origin: results[0].geometry.location,
            destination: latLng,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING
        };
        var name = ' ' + results[0].name;
        $('#train h3').append(name);
        trainService.route(request, function(response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                trainDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
        });
    }
}

function busRoute(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        var request = {
            origin: results[0].geometry.location,
            destination: latLng,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING
        };
        var name = ' ' + results[0].name;
        $('#bus h3').append(name);
        busService.route(request, function(response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                busDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
        });
    }
}

function airportRoute(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        var request = {
            origin: results[0].geometry.location,
            destination: latLng,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        var name = ' ' + results[0].name;
        $('#airport h3').append(name);
        airportService.route(request, function(response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                airportDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
        });
    }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialise);
```

**END OF UPDATED CODE -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

I want to generate dynamic directions results based on a specific lat/long for the destination while generating the origin based on the lat/long of closest type (train_station, bus_station and airport) to the destination.

I'm part way there as in I'm able to get a list of places and their related lat/long values based on a radius of '500' but I need to modify the code, so that it only gets the closest result for each type, so essentially the first found.

I'd also like to do it in a way where I am able to generate a result for each type. My code so far is:

```
// Google Maps
var lat = $('#map').data('lat');
var lng = $('#map').data('lng');

var markerImage = {
    url: '/img/marker.png'
}

var eventTitle = $('.title').data('event-title');
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

function initialise() {

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: latLng
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions'));

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map,
        title: eventTitle,
        icon: markerImage
    });

    var request = {
        location: latLng,
        radius: '500',
        types: ['train_station']
    };

    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

    service.nearbySearch(request, calcRoute);
}

function calcRoute(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        for (var i = 0, result; result = results[i]; i++) {
            var directionsRequest = {
                origin: result.geometry.location,
                destination: latLng,
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING
            };
            directionsService.route(directionsRequest, function(response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialise);
```

**EDIT**: Getting closer to the mark with: http://paste.laravel.com/1eHK but I need now to only get the closest/first place result for each type.

Seems a bit messy and overkill/not DRY but it works to a point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want the first result (which I don't know that you do):

```
function calcRoute(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          var directionsRequest = {
              origin: results[0].geometry.location,
              destination: latLng,
              travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING
          };
          directionsService.route(directionsRequest, function(response, status) {
              if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                  directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
              } 
              else alert ("Directions request failed:"+status);
          });
    }
}
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_directionsFromPlacesA.html)

Comment: Yes it does as an example for a single search and an answer to your original question.  That code uses the default rankBy PROMINENCE and returns the first result.  And the working example uses rankBy DISTANCE for bus and train, rankBy PROMINENCE for airport.  It even uses your coordinates...